# How to access Apple Pay transaction History made by iOS App?

Tags: ios, swift, applepay

I have done the Apple Pay integration `https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/apple_pay/setting_up_apple_pay_requirements` and tested `https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/`. 
I have done the testing successfully by using sandbox and real cards but cannot see the transaction history for any of them. There is no record on Card Issuer Bank statement.
I've followed the following guidelines to check transaction records`https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph7b666943a/ios` but couldn't see any change?

Has anyone done this yet? if yes, then please guide me through the process to check the transaction history record of payments made by Apple Pay iOS app and where can developer(retailer/owner of the app) can see the transactions done by user?